# DatePicker control shown twice in Android >=4.0 under phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, datepicker

This is more of question with an answer

We had a problem where a datepicker control would be shown twice after clicking a field of date, we also used a datepicker plugin for phonegap, the problem was that in versions 4.0 of Android the browser handles date fields differently, so the sollutions is either remove type on html field if date or don't use datepicker control.